# Inherit a parent Menu OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo, inheritance

I would like to have my module menu "nested" inside Purchase Orders in the OpenErp's Purchase App.

Right now my module has the following  statements (The parent being itself)

```
<menuitem id="certificados_parent" name="Certificados" icon="terp-partner"/>
<menuitem id="menu_certificados_parent" name="Manejo de los certificados" parent="certificados_parent"></menuitem>
<menuitem action="action_certificados_certificados" id="menu_certificados_certificados" parent="menu_certificados_parent" string="Result"/>
```

This is the code from my form tree

```
<record id="student_certificados_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">certificados.result.form</field>
    <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Introducir los datos" >

            <field name="Codigo Arancelario" />
            <field name="Descripcion Arancelaria" />
            <field name="Especificaciones Tecnicas" />
            <field name="Cantidad" />
            <field name="Precio Unitario Declarado" />
            <field name="Valor En Divisas" />
            </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

On the other hand i see this parent form code in a view from another module "purchase Requisition"(purchase_requisition_view.xml)

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="purchase_order_form_inherit">
    <field name="name">purchase.order.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="validator" position="before">
            <field name="requisition_id"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

What should i do to accomplish this task, is the product requisition code a clue?

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more detail what you wann do?

Answer (score 2):

Go to purchase view xml file and search for menu item Purchase use that menu id as parent for your Menu parent="model.xml_id" example =purchase.menu_12" some thing like this replace menu_12 with purchase menu's id Use this in your menu item  as Parent.

Purchase Requisition View
No,it is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
<menuitem action="mrp_production_action" id="menu_mrp_production_action"
    parent="menu_mrp_manufacturing" sequence="1"/>
```

get ID from that menu & create menu in your module & give that menu id as a parent

Answer (score 1):

```
<menuitem id="menu_certificados_parent" name="Manejo de los certificados" parent="base.menu_purchase_root"></menuitem>
<menuitem action="action_certificados_certificados" id="menu_certificados_certificados" parent="menu_certificados_parent" string="Result"/>
```

Use this code in your Module.I hope its working